# Android, Button won't function within Try Catch block

Tags: android, button, try-catch

I'm writing a program to take user input using edittext and turn a textview into to display that text.

The input is number and I have converted the String into Integer value properly, the only issue is that I have to use a try catch block to catch Number Format Error. The issue is that I must include the button for setting the TextView to the inputted, within the try catch block for the button to know what the values set by the user are.

```
try{

     EditText hour = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hourin);

     EditText  min = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.minin);

     final TextView FinalTime = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.FinalTimeDisplay);


     String hoursString = hour.getText().toString();
     String minsString = min.getText().toString();


     int hours = Integer.parseInt(hoursString);
     int mins = Integer.parseInt(minsString);


    final String time = (hours + ":" + mins);

    Button Submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {


               FinalTime.setText(time);

        }
    });

    } catch (NumberFormatException e){

    }
```

Comment: move this `String hoursString = hour.getText().toString();
     String minsString = min.getText().toString();` to `onClick`. Extract the exception part form the logcat and post it here

Comment: see this [link](http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2011/09/11/android-tutorial-7-how-to-debug-the-android-mobile-application-with-logcat/) to know about stack trace..

Comment: Is there even an exception? I'm confused on what the problem is. Crashing, not functioning properly (if so how?), etc...

Comment: The app will crash on launch without the try catch block, if I use the try catch block over the entire statement the button Submit does nothing the TextView remains the same.

Comment: Why don't you put the `try/catch` block inside the `onClick()`? Also, does it catch a number format exception? If so, this would keep it from changing the text. You really should log the exception (at least) instead of doing nothing in the `catch` block.

Comment: The app doesn't function when try catch surrounds whats inside the onClick(), Sorry I'm kinda new to programming with android I'm not sure about log the exception

Comment: We really need more info here to help you.  I suggest using the tried and true method of `Log.v(String {whereyouareinthecode}, String {some value, some place, etc.});` -the old "print statements" debugging method.  You need to give us more to work with, mate.  Check the logcat for these messages and let us know what you see.

Comment: Success it works I forgot to put the String hourString into the onClick() then I put the try catch within the onClick() thank You Very much.

Comment: It says I cannot post the answer for 8 hours but I will post it later thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
          Button Submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
          Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {

                    int hours = 0;
                    int mins = 0;
                    int breaktimes = 0;

                    hours = Integer.parseInt(hour.getText().toString());
                    mins = Integer.parseInt(min.getText().toString());
                    breaktimes = Integer.parseInt(breaktime.getText().toString());  

                    mins = (mins + breaktimes);
                    if (mins >= 60){
                        hours = hours + 1;
                        mins = mins - 60;
                    }

                    if (hours > 12){
                        hours = hours - 12;
                    } 


                if (mins < 10){ 
               FinalTime.setText(hours +":" +"0"+ mins);
                }else{
                    FinalTime.setText(hours + ":" +mins);
                }
            }catch (NumberFormatException e){

            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: Adding some explanation would be great :)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, u need to add **@Override** decorator top of the `public void onClick()` ?!

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    FinalTime.setText(time);
}
```